# Referencing within an align environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align

The following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \\ \nonumber
  E=mc^2 \label{eq1}
\end{align}

ref \ref{eq1}
\end{document}
```

Does not display the reference `\ref{eq1}`. Why?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The `\label` is on the same equation line (not code line) as the `\nonumber` and therefore doesn't get any equation number to label and to reference later. You need to move `\nonumber` (or the `\label`) before the `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \nonumber \\
  E=mc^2 \label{eq1}
\end{align}

ref \ref{eq1}
\end{document}
```

In the above case the equation number is placed in the second row. If you want it in the first then place the `\nonumber` after the `\\` but the `\label` before it.

Answer (score 16):

use it this way:

```
\begin{align}
  E=mc^2 \nonumber\\ 
  E=mc^2 \label{eq1}
\end{align}

ref \ref{eq1}
```

Set `\nonumber` *before* the double backslash

Answer (score 5):

For posterity: I solved this problem by commenting out the package cleverref, which was somehow interfering with my ability to reference equation numbers in the usual non-clever way (this is not the problem OP had, but this post is a top hit on google when I searched for my symptoms so I'm leaving a comment here).

Answer (score 0):

For further reference: I solved the same issue by placing the label just next to the \begin{align} command (and with \usepackage{cleveref} active):

```
\begin{align}\label{eq1}
E=mc^2 \nonumber\\
E=mc^2`
\end{align}
```

In the text: "... `equation~\ref{eq1}`"

Comment: That works only by chance. The `\label` should be in the numbered row, not in the unnumbered one.